# Propagate calculation result

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to initialize an array `b` similar to this, but faster:

```
a = [0.53, 0.66, 0.064, 0.94, 0.44]
b = [0.0]*5
x = 14.3
for i in range(5):
    x = b[i] = a[i]*0.1 + x*0.9
```

Is there something in numpy for that purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ugly but vectorized numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.53, 0.66, 0.064, 0.94, 0.44])
x = 14.3
idx = np.arange(a.size)
0.9 ** idx * (0.1 * (a * 0.9 ** (-idx)).cumsum() + x * 0.9)
# array([12.923    , 11.6967   , 10.53343  ,  9.574087 ,  8.6606783])
```

Result from `for` loop:

```
a = [0.53, 0.66, 0.064, 0.94, 0.44]
b = [0.0]*5
x = 14.3
for i in range(5):
    x = b[i] = a[i]*0.1 + x*0.9

b
#[12.923000000000002,
# 11.696700000000003,
# 10.533430000000003,
# 9.574087000000002,
# 8.660678300000002]
```

This is because:

[image]

And components in the result can be vectorized correspondingly, note the sum of `a` terms in the inner parenthesis is vectorized as `cumsum`.

Comment: This is the right way to do so , I think I am in the wrong direction to combine all x rather than a , which will create the problem with agg .

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can break down and find the correlation between each steps

```
***x0=x0***

***x1=a[0]*0.1 + x0*0.9***

***x2=a[1]*0.1 + x1*0.9=a[1]*0.1 + (a[0]*0.1 + x0*0.9)*0.9***
```

So ***`xn=an*0.1+an-1*0.1*0.9+...+a0*0.1*0.9**n-1+x0*0.9**n`***

```
n=np.array(0.9)**np.arange(len(a))


sum(a[::-1]*n)*0.1+x*(0.9**(len(a)))
Out[338]: 8.6606783
```

Update output  `array`

```
np.diag(np.fliplr(((a*n[::-1])*0.1).cumsum()/n[:,None]+x*(0.9**(np.arange(1,len(a)+1)))))[::-1]
Out[472]: array([12.923    , 11.6967   , 10.53343  ,  9.574087 ,  8.6606783])
```

Comment: Hm, interesting. But shouldn't the output be an array?

Comment: @RafaelC if need , just make this as a example and true to match the for loop output . :-)

Comment: `np.array(np.arange())` is redundant, and you probably need `cumsum`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite your loop to analyze it more closely:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    b[i] = a[i]*0.1 + b[i-1]*0.9
```

This makes it clear that the calculation is recursive. That is, the value of `b[i]` depends on the value of `b[i-1]`. This means that you cannot vectorize the calculation. Vectorizing requires that each element of the result vector is independent of all other elements.

Comment: I realize that, my question was if numpy had anything for me in this regard? Or can I safely conclude that numpy is vector math only?

Comment: @JonasByström A lot of the speed you can see from numpy is from vector and matrix math because these operations can often run many calculations in parallel.

Comment: @JonasByström If you can solve the recurrence relation in terms of `i`, you can make some improvements to your loop and maybe apply numpy to it.